# HP Laser Jet 1020 plus installation

Tags: system-installation, printing, hp

In Ubuntu 12.04 on switching on the printer the system automatically recognized the plug in but in Ubuntu 14.04 this would not happen.

I wish someone would show me the method by which I can install HP Laserjet 1020 plus driver and plugin easily.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui`

Comment: This worked for me:cd ~/Downloads

sudo wget -c "http://kaz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hplip/hplip/3.13.11/hplip-3.13.11.run"

sudo sh hplip-3.13.11.run And finally 'sudo apt-get install hplip-gui'

Comment: congratualations for solving this.  Please post an answer and you'll be able to accept your own answer to close the thread.  Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me : https://askubuntu.com/a/1345289/866008

Answer (score 8):

Now I have got some easier solution to my own problem:

Just use the command : `hp-doctor`

I had to answer some question during the process. And it downloaded all the necessary drivers / plug-ins. That's all.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: In case you get error described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1759278) just do `python3 /usr/bin/hp-doctor`

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS as `getweb` didn't worked (`getweb: Couldn't download http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/firmware/sihp1018.tar.gz`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way how OP has solved his problem in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452161/hp-laser-jet-1020-plus-installation#comment600015_452161),

#### Step-1 :

Change directory to Downloads where the `hplip` will be downloaded. Write in a terminal,

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

#### Step-2 :

Download `hplip-3.13.11.run` from the terminal using `wget` as,

```
wget -c http://kaz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hplip/hplip/3.13.11/hplip-3.13.11.run%22
```

***Note:*** Newer version of `hplip` is available. you can check [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/)

#### Step-3 :

Run the package as superuser. You may need to use the package name that you downloaded. Here,

```
sudo sh hplip-3.13.11.run
```

#### Step-4 :

Install `hplip-gui` using `apt` from the terminal as,

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed steps given in the blog https://blog.hostonnet.com/how-to-install-hp-laser-jet-1020-plus printer. These are on terminal enter following steps.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove hplip cups-filters cups hplip-data system-config-printer-udev
sudo apt install build-essential tix groff dc cups
sudo apt install cups-filters unp system-config-printer-gnome
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip
cd /tmp
rm foo*
wget -c http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
unp foo2zjs.tar.gz
cd foo2zjs/
make
./getweb 1020
sudo make install
sudo make install-hotplug
```

Unplug and replug USB printer.

Type `system-config-printer`, select foo2zjs as the printer driver.
Errors can be checked by entering `tail /var/log/syslog`

Comment: *Blog not found*

Comment: Not enough effort was made to research this issue by using HP or ubuntu sites.