# How to install Hp laser jet 1020 plus printer?

Tags: 14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu (14.04). I have to print some documents, but I can't set up my printer (Hp laser jet 1020 plus). Please tell me the proper way to set-up and install it.

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452161/hp-laser-jet-1020-plus-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your computer to the printer.  Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the command

```
hp-setup
```

The program will guide you through the steps of setting up the printer.